# Parse words from text using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, vb.net

I have an HTML page that has elements such as

```
<li id="ctl00_rpPublication_ctl61_liPublication" data-pmid="19917728">
<li id="ctl00_rpPublication_ctl62_liPublication" data-pmid="19887554">
<li id="ctl00_rpPublication_ctl63_liPublication" data-pmid="19851314">
```

I know that I can parse the page using HTML-Agility or even just doing a loop finding the index of data-pmid but I would like to accomplish this using Regex if possible. I need to read the text page and end up with a comma separated string of all of the values of data-pmid.  such as

```
value = 19917728,19887554,19851314
```

I can do a pattern matching of data-pmid but do not know how to get the values between the double quotes.

The reason I would like to use Regex is that I can use the code in various places, such as vb.net or javascript.  Is this a good use for Regex?  The page could have 100 values.

Comment: `.*data-pmid=\"([0-9]{1,})\".*` I think this regex should work, you will get number in match group

Comment: Although the regex may be the same, all the code to use it will be different in different languages and you will not be able to take advantage of things like [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) in JavaScript or the robustness of HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: Be aware of how the HTML is given to you. It could have line endings or none, or even a combination. I agree with A. Morton's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```js
let data = `<li id="ctl00_rpPublication_ctl61_liPublication" data-pmid="19917728">
<li id="ctl00_rpPublication_ctl62_liPublication" data-pmid="19887554">
<li id="ctl00_rpPublication_ctl63_liPublication" data-pmid="19851314">`;

let rx = /data-pmid="([^"]+)"/g;

match = rx.exec(data);
while (match != null) {
  // matched text: match[0]
  // match start: match.index
  // capturing group n: match[n]
  console.log(match[1])
  match = rx.exec(data);
}
```

Comment: Works great in my javaScript.  Any idea how to run it in vb,net?  I can double quote the   Dim re As Regex = New Regex("/data-pmid=""([^""]+)""/g") but it does not like the ^""  Thanks

Comment: sorry-- it was not the Regex it was the text string-- thanks